# How to set allowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount property for Webview in MAUI?

Tags: webview, maui, webview2, maui-windows, maui-community-toolkit

We have developed MAUI application and we are displaying our website in WebView control of MAUI.

Our website requires 2FA but after entering our credentials the page does not load since Device ID is not passed with the Webview.

After going through this article https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/550 we found that we have to enable allowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount to true in WebView environment.

Please let us know how can we achieve the same, so that Device ID gets passed with WebView.

Note - We are not able to find this property in MAUI WebView but we are able to find the property in WPF WebView2 control.

We tried to search for allowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount  property in MAUI but we are not able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Maui on the windows platform is based on the WinUI 3. And the `allowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount` property is not supported in the winui 3 now.

You can follow up this issue about [WebView2 does not support passing in a CoreWebView2Environment](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/1170) on the github.

And I have created a new project to test. The `allowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount` property always used in the native webview2 such as :

```
  CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions webViewEnvironmentOptions = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions(allowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount: _config.UseWindowsAuth);
  var webView2Environment = CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(browserExecutableFolder: null, userDataFolder: _cacheFolderPath, options: webViewEnvironmentOptions).Result;
         
  webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(webView2Environment);
```

But when I used the `(webview.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2)` to get the webview2 in the maui. I found that the `EnsureCoreWebView2Async()` and the `CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync` didn't have any parameter.

Comment: So as of now there is no way for me to use this property "allowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount" with WebView in MAUI ?

Comment: Yes, you can't use it in the maui for now. @Sanket